# Python append to list or ignore

Tags: python, list

I want make an array as follow :

```
for i in range(0, len(final), 3):
    ar.append(
        (
            final[i] + 100,
            final[i+1] + 100,
            final[i+2] + 100
        )
    )
```

but there is a simple problem. length of **final** is about 2682715 and i have exception for list index when reach `2682714` with `step=3`

```
final[2682714] = OK
final[2682715] = OK
final[2682716] = ERROR
```

How can i handle that? we can use `try/except IndexError` but whole item will be ignored

Comment: What should the last element of `ar` be? `(final[2682714], final[2682715])`

Comment: `final[2682715]` @Joren485

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Comment: What do you mean with the "whole item will be ignored"?

Comment: i want two last items and `except` will be ignored them @SeppeMariën

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final = range(31)
ar = []
for i in range(0, len(final), 3):
    ar.append(tuple(final[i:i+3]))

print(ar)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11), (12, 13, 14), (15, 16, 17), (18,
19, 20), (21, 22, 23), (24, 25, 26), (27, 28, 29),(30,)]
```

Your list length is divisible by 3 - you last element would be the last triplet , not a tuple with only one element...

Mine is not divisible by 3 without rest, so I have an incomplete `tuple` at the end.

Using the list comprehension `tuple(final[i:i+3])` will ensure you do not overstep the boundaries of `final` and the remaining `1` or `2` numbers are in the last `tuple`.

Comment: Note, `list(range(31))` isn't actually necessary, since `range` objects are sequences that support `len` and slicing...

Comment: OK, it's good ... but what about if i want add some number with them ? for example `final[i]+100, final[i+1]+100, final[i+2]+100` we can't use tuple at this situation... is it possible ?

Comment: @ArashHatami not specified in your question so far. Do you want to add the same constant to every one?

Comment: @ArashHatami  `ar.append( tuple([x+100 for x in final[i:i+3]]))`

Answer (score 2):

you can use list comprehension:

```
final = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
ar = []
ar = [final[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(final), 3)]
print(ar)
```

output:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 7), (8, 9, 10), (11, 12, 13), (14, 15)]
```

Comment: i updated my answer, it will give you now the last items

Answer (score 2):

slicing is nice, for one line add a `zip`

```
a = [*range(9)]

[*zip(a[::3], a[1::3], a[2::3])]

Out[321]: [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]
```

`zip` automatically drops extra elements that don't make up a tripple

Comment: thats `0+every 3`, `skip 1+every 3`, `skip 2+every3` and zipped? Neat